# Django pagination (get page no. corresponding to the object)

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers, django-pagination

I have a paginate I am trying to get the index page from an object page (sort of pagination in reverse)

The get_paginated_posts returns a paginator for the model `Post`:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_paginated_posts(self, request=None):
        if request and request.user.has_perm('blog.change_post'):
            posts = super(PostManager, self).filter(is_update=False)
        else:        
            posts = super(PostManager, self).filter(publish=True, is_update=False)
        return Paginator(posts, POSTS_PER_PAGE)
    .
    .
```

This is my model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    def get_page(self, request=None):
        paginator = Post.objects.get_paginated_posts(request)
        for i in range(1, paginator.num_pages+1):
            if self in paginator.page(i).object_list:                
                return i
            pass
        return False
```

My concern is the `Post.objects.get_paginated_posts` call in the get_page function.
**Is it right to call `Post` class from an instance? Is there any other better way to do this possible?**
**Why cannot I call `super(Post, self).objects.get_paginated_posts` to do the same?**
I understand that `self.objects.get_paginated_posts` wont work because of absent access for the object to its manager.

### Solved

Final code as suggested by Tomasz Elendt:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_paginated_posts(self, user=None):
        if user and user.has_perm('blog.change_post'):
            posts = super(PostManager, self).filter(is_update=False)
        else:        
            posts = super(PostManager, self).filter(publish=True, is_update=False)
        return Paginator(posts, POSTS_PER_PAGE)

class Post(models.Model):
    .
    def get_page(self, request=None):
        return self._default_manager.filter(is_update = False, time__gt=self.time).count()/POSTS_PER_PAGE +1 
        #Just a one line now :P
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the best idea what you're doing. Try to imagine how many queries it'll be translated to -- in the worst case you'd need to retrieve all user's posts from database!

I assume that you have some predefined ordering in your `Post` model (the one that `Paginator` uses). Use that to obtain the number of user's posts that precede that specific post record. If you divide that number by the `POSTS_PER_PAGE` value you'll get your page number.

IMHO using `PostManager` in `Post` methods is ok. What's not ok is that you're passing request object to it while I think you should use `user_id` for that (and permission checking should be really part of a view logic).

**EDIT:** example

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

POSTS_PER_PAGE = 10

class Post(models.Model):
    """
    >>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    >>> from django.db import connection
    >>> from django.conf import settings
    >>>
    >>> user = User.objects.create_user("test", "test@domain.com")
    >>> for i in xrange(100):
    ...     p = Post.objects.create(author=user,
    ...                             pub_date=datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=i))
    >>> post = Post.objects.all()[68]
    >>> settings.DEBUG = True    # monkey-patching settings - ugly
    >>> connection.queries = []  # cleaning previous queries
    >>> post.get_page()
    7
    >>> len(connection.queries)  # print number of queries of `get_page` call
    1
    """
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pub_date"]

    def get_page(self):
        return self._default_manager.filter(author__id=self.author_id).filter(
            pub_date__gt=self.pub_date).count() / POSTS_PER_PAGE + 1
```

Comment: Sorry about the modulo thing - I had division in mind. I added a simple example. You can run it by `./manage.py test module_name`. The `+1` is there because Django's `Paginator.page` gives 1-based index result.

Comment: `super(Post, self).objects` doesn't work. What you're looking for is probably `self._default_manager`

Comment: thanks @tomasz Your fix works. Earlier I wasn't getting wrong results from doc tests then on a deeper look found out it was because of all the posts got same date-time, hence wrong ordering.